# In a many to many relationship , how to retrieve the values like 2-D array with help of linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-5

I have two tables User and Item with unique values for which I created a many to many relationship in the table list. The tables created looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Item
(
Item_Id int identity(1,1) not null,
Item_Name varchar(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (Item_Id)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.List
(
Item_Id int not null,
Users_Id varchar(11) not null,
);
```

Now if the values in the List table looks something like this

```
    UserID    |   ItemID
  ---------------------------
    User1         1 
    User1         2 
    User2         3 
    User2         1
```

How do I retrieve the values from the table where for each ItemId, I can list the Users who have requested the item.

```
1:User1,User2
2:User1
3:User2
```

For doing this I am trying to find out for each Item Id who are all its users. The database I use here is SQL server and I know there is a concept called Linq in C# by which I can query and store the results but I am completely clueless on how to do this.

I referred to other posts in which they had similar queries but since I am new to the concept I do not understand how to execute the query and how to store the result. And also I want to do this over the ADO.NET connection that I already have.

My primary purpose is to find a User who has made similar request i.e

```
  If User1 has made requests for item 1,2,5
  If User2 has made requests for item 1,2,4
  If User3 has made requests for item 1,3,4
```

for User1 the related users must be listed as User2(common with User1 with 2 items) and then User3(common with User1 with only one item).

Can I still proceed with the linq approach or is there a better approach to satisfy my primary purpose???
Please help me with examples and step by step guide on how to achieve this.....

Answer (score 0):

```
// your data
var data = new[]{
            new {UserId="User1", ItemId=1},
            new {UserId="User1", ItemId=2},
            new {UserId="User2", ItemId=3},
            new {UserId="User2", ItemId=1}
        };

// you may use it with the db context from your EF, eg. context.items.ToLookup(...
var result = data.ToLookup(p => p.ItemId, p => p.UserId);

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, string.Join(", ", item));
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary

```css
            // your data
            var data = new[]{
            new {UserId="User1", ItemId=1},
            new {UserId="User1", ItemId=2},
            new {UserId="User2", ItemId=3},
            new {UserId="User2", ItemId=1}
            };


            var dict = data.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.ItemId, y => y.UserId)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.ToList());

            foreach (var key in dict.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Item ID : {0}, Values : {1}", key, string.Join(",",dict[key].ToArray()));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();​
```